# How can I track web events on Safari with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I am unable to track web conversions happening on safari browser. I already setup conversion linker tag but still unable to record conversions. Upon disabling the option of prevent cross site tracking in Safari the event tracking option starts working but when prevent cross site tracking option is on safari is not allowing me to record events. Is there any way through which I can get the events recorded while enabling prevent cross site tracking on Safari?

Comment: Could you please add some more details?  Are you trying to send events to Google Analytics?  Are there any errors in the console about this?  Safari's [Intelligent Tracking Prevention](https://webkit.org/?s=privacy) (which is what the `Prevent cross-site tracking` checkbox controls) does stuff like block third-party cookies, but it doesn't block Google Analytics network calls or that kind of thing.  Do you have any other information that might help me understand the problem?